# Android resource compilation failed error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''

Tags: android, build

I am trying to build my project and I face this error I don't know how to fix it

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'

}
```

Android resource compilation failed :

> C:\Users\Google Inc\Desktop\education\Education\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1952: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
>   C:\Users\Google Inc\Desktop\education\Education\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1952: error: resource previously defined here.
>   C:\Users\Google Inc\Desktop\education\Education\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: error: file failed to compile.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: have you checked that file for a duplicated attribute value?